# Salesforce Flow - Get opportunities created yesterday

Tags: visual-workflow

I would like to get all the opportunities created yesterday.  So, my formula variable "Yesterday" is as follow: ( {!$Flow.CurrentDate} - 1 ). However, when I added this variable into the opportunity filter condition, CreatedDate equals "Yesterday".  It does not return any opportunities and I'm expected 4, which I created with createddate equals to "Yesterday". Created date is my only filter criteria.

Is my "Yesterday" formula correct?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $Flow.CurrentDate returns a Date, and the CreatedDate on your Opportunity is a DateTime.  So first you might think you just need to match them up - but it appears you cannot do these sorts of date comparisons in flow conditions as per:

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000PcZ1QAK

So the workaround they recommend is to create a checkbox formula field on the Opportunity (in your case) which is checked when your condition is true (CreatedDate is yesterday).

Then in your flow, check that this checkbox is true.

Comment: Thank you for you feedback. Much appreciated it.